# How to delete buffered data in a buffered OutputStream?

Tags: java, buffer, outputstream

It is possible to skip data from an InputStream

> in.skip(in.available());

but if you want to do something similar with OutputStream I've found

> socket.getOutputStream().flush();

But that's not the same, flush will transmit the buffered data instead of ignoring it.

Is there any possibility of deleting buffered data?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The situation is a client-server application, when a new command is send (from client) 
it (try) to be sure that the answer read will correspond to the last command sent.

Some commands are sent by (human-fired) events, and others are sent by automatic threads.
If a command is on buffer and a new one is send then the answer will be for the first one, causing desynchronization.

Of course a synchronized method plus a flag called "waitingCommand" could be the safer approach but as the communication is not reliable, this approach is slow (depends on timeouts ). That's why I've asked for the skip method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no sure if it makes sense, but you can try:

```
class MyBufferedOutputStream extends java.io.BufferedOutputStream {

    public MyBufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    /** throw away everything in a buffer without writing it */
    public synchronized void skip() {
        count = 0; 
    }

}
```

Comment: I think Secundary buffer seems to be the answer, thanks for the implementation example

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove data you could have sent.  You can write the data into an in-memory OutputStream like ByteArrayOutputStream and copy only the portions you want.

Answer (score 2):

What does it mean to "skip" outputting data?

Once the data is in the buffer, there's no way to get it back or remove it. I suggest checking if you want to skip the data **before** you write it to the `OutputStream`. Either that, or have your own secondary buffer that you can modify at will.

Comment: Secundary buffer seems to be the answer

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make any sense. Throwing away pending requests will just make your application protocol problem worse. What happens to the guy that is waiting for the response to the request that got deleted? What happened to the functionality that that request was supposed to implement? You need to rethink all this from another point of view. If you have a single connection to a server that is executing request/response transactions for this client, the protocol is already sequential. You will have to synchronize on e.g. the socket at the point of writing & flushing the request and reading the response, but you're not losing any performance by this as the processing at the other end is sequentialized anyway. You don't need a 'waitingCommand' flag as well, just synchronization.

Comment: I would agree, I give +1 anyway because you understand the problem, but *the channel is not reliable at all*, there are a lot of data loss and reconnections, so to minimize the effect for the user, I would add a second method (not totally desynchronized but with priority) that discard the automated command to address the recent human-orders first, blocking every transmission to timeout would becomes very slow, second, with "waitngCommand" I mean the same that "just synchronization", the flag is just to avoid "spurious wakeup" is always recomended for synchronization to check a variable.thanks

Comment: @Hernán Eche what kind of a channel is this? And maybe you should be using two channels, one for automated stuff and one for user stuff? And I still don't get this stuff about the boolean. You need a boolean with wait()/notify(), not with synchronization (synchronized() keyword).

Comment: Hello, well wait() and notify() are not really separable of *synchronized* keyword, they work together. The channel is a GSM/GPRS network(ugly channel). About the boolean (don't need to be boolean) see this http://vladimir_prus.blogspot.com/2005/07/spurious-wakeups.html http://www.devguli.com/blog/eng/spurious-wakeup/   greetings!

Comment: @Hernán Eche I repeat. The boolean is needed with wait/notify. It is not needed without them. You can synchronize perfectly well without using wait/notify at all, and that is what I am recommending for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are controlling the data written to OutputStream, just don't write pieces that you don't need. OutputStream by contract, does not ensure when data is actually written, so it doesn't make much sense to have skip method.

Comment: See edit, I can't have total control of data written, or if I do it, comunication become slower

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do to "ignore" output data, is not to write it at first.